# How to set parents folder name and get the uploaded image id for Google Drive Api javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api, google-drive-api

I have implemented this by following [this](https://codingshiksha.com/how-to-upload-files-to-google-drive-in-javascript-using-google-drive-rest-api-v3) tutorial and it's working perfectly. After successful authentication the image is uploading on my `Google Drive` perfectly. But now I want to know

1. how can I add parent's folder name directory `(parent/folderOne/folderTwo)` for my uploaded image?
2. And I also need the `fileID` for newly uploaded image.
   In java script I can do that in

```
const fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'any_file_name',
        parents: ['1xxxXj_sdsdsdsd0Rw6qDf0jLukG6eEUl']
};
```

But here I don't have any knowledge on `ajax`, so any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!
This is the code for uploading to `Google Drive`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const code = urlParams.get('code');
    const redirect_uri = "http://localhost/googleDriveUpload/upload.html" // replace with your redirect_uri;
    const client_secret = "***********"; // replace with your client secret
    const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    var access_token= "";
    var client_id = "********************"// replace it with your client id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
        data: {code:code
            ,redirect_uri:redirect_uri,
            client_secret:client_secret,
        client_id:client_id,
        scope:scope,
        grant_type:"authorization_code"},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resultData) {
           localStorage.setItem("accessToken",resultData.access_token);
           localStorage.setItem("refreshToken",resultData.refreshToken);
           localStorage.setItem("expires_in",resultData.expires_in);
           window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/GitLoginApp/" + "upload.html");
        }
  });

    function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
        return url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
    }

    var Upload = function (file) {
        this.file = file;
    };

    Upload.prototype.getType = function() {
        localStorage.setItem("type",this.file.type);
        return this.file.type;
    };
    Upload.prototype.getSize = function() {
        localStorage.setItem("size",this.file.size);
        return this.file.size;
    };
    Upload.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this.file.name;
    };
    Upload.prototype.doUpload = function () {
        var that = this;
        var formData = new FormData();

        // add assoc key values, this will be posts values
        formData.append("file", this.file, this.getName());
        formData.append("upload_file", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
            },
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files",
            data:{
                uploadType:"media"
            },
            xhr: function () {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', that.progressHandling, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            async: true,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            timeout: 60000
        });
    };

    Upload.prototype.progressHandling = function (event) {
        var percent = 0;
        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
        var total = event.total;
        var progress_bar_id = "#progress-wrp";
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
        }
        // update progressbars classes so it fits your code
        $(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").css("width", +percent + "%");
        $(progress_bar_id + " .status").text(percent + "%");
    };

    $("#upload").on("click", function (e) {
        var file = $("#files")[0].files[0];
        var upload = new Upload(file);

        // maby check size or type here with upload.getSize() and upload.getType()

        // execute upload
        upload.doUpload();
    });
});
```

Comment: YOu should be able to set the parent id as part of the formData.  You can either add it when you are uploading the image.  Your going to have to find the parent file id in order to set that.  You will need to do a file.list and find the parent file id that you wish to upload to.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic check number 4 we do not supply tutorials we help you fix your code.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your comment. Ok I will follow it from the next time.